# Invoke-ASCmd warning - Is this why the cube doesn't deploy?

Tags: powershell, ssas, ssas-2012, ascmd

SSAS 2012 and Powershell 5.0> I have a deployment automation process that runs the Deployment.exe wizard in silent mode to create an XMLA file and then uses Invoke-ASCmd to deploy the SSAS project to an SSAS server. It works fine for our proof-of-concept Tabular model, but fails on the Dimensional Cube that runs against AdventureWorks-DW. The project builds fine in VS2012 and runs locally.

I get this error out of ASCmd:

```
The name in the end tag of the element must match the element type in the start tag.
```

Followed by a bunch of these

```
Query (1, 1) Parser: The syntax for '<' is incorrect.
```

I suspect this is related to the old error in ASCmd involving RegEx and parsing the XML looking for Go commands ([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de967b9b-baf3-4a9b-a092-230510a15856/xmla-with-delimited-htmlencoded-special-characters?forum=sqlanalysisservices)), but I can't prove it. I do know the model has two Translations specified for the cube but try as I might I can't permanently delete them. I'm not sure if they're related but it's a thought.

Anyone run into this problem?

Deployment command:

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe "AHP_AdventureWorksDW2012.asdatabase" /o:"AHP_AdventureWorksDW2012.xmla" /s:log.txt /d
```

Powershell ASCmd:

```
Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile D:\a5\AHP_AdventureWorksDW2012_Dim\MS_Deploy_SQL_SSAS_Dim_2_1\trunk_Showcase_AHP_AdventureWorksDW2012\AHP_AdventureWorksDW2012.xmla -Server AD1HFDASST9C1\MSBI
```

Comment: You should probably show in your question the "ASCmd" command you are using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we run into this problem when generated with Deployment utility files exceeded some size limit; the error reported by ASCMD was exactly the same. Fix - switch to cube deployment with Deployment utility itself with command like:

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe <cube.asdatabase> /s
```

This is generating diff and deploying it on the fly.

Comment: I thought about this approach but I can't find any docs on how you run it other than specifying "/s". Is that all there is?

Comment: Ran Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe "AHP_AdventureWorksDW2012.asdatabase" /s and it worked! Much simpler.